# Embed prev and next buttons into image

Tags: html, css

I have the following simple `HMTL` and `CSS` code which you can also find in the `JSfiddle` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/koanfw15/38/):

```css
body {
  height: 500px;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: blue;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.image_details {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: yellow;
 
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
}

.image img {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 background-color: red;
 
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
}

.prev_button {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
   background-color: blue;
}

.next_button {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
 <div class="image_details"> <img src="http://placehold.it/101x101"> </div>
</div>

 <div class="prev_button"> PREVIOUS </div>
 <div class="next_button"> NEXT </div>
```

As you can see in the code above I want to have an `image` and a `prev` and `next` button. However, instead of having the `prev` and `next` buttons below the `image` I would like to have them on the **left center** and on the **right center** in the `image`.

What do I have to change in my code to make this work?

Comment: Can you show a picture of what you want? Do you want the controls next to the image (left, right) or on top of it (left, right)?

Comment: I want them on top of it.

Comment: By the way putting them on the left or right side next to the image might be also an option for me later. In this case I put the solution here http://jsfiddle.net/koanfw15/38/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy method is to use absolute positioning. Insert the buttons as children of  `.image` and set the parent to `position: relative`. The children need `position: absolute;` and have to be positioned, as you can see in my full example. I also remove the heights from your CSS so avoid stretching the img.

```css
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  position: relative;
}

.image_details {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.prev_button, .next_button {
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: blue;
}

.prev_button {
  left: 0;
}

.next_button {
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
 <div class="image_details"><img src="http://placehold.it/101x101"></div>
 <div class="prev_button">PREVIOUS</div>
 <div class="next_button">NEXT</div>
</div>
```